# std::ostringstream overwriting initializing string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stl, c++17

The following code results in "0004567" on [clang++-7](https://repl.it/@agustinf_/ostringstream-bug-or-anti-feature#main.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ostringstream oss{"1234567"};
    oss << "000";
    cout << oss.str() << endl;
}
```

Now is this correct STL implementation?

I can't think of how is it useful to initialize with a string that will be overwritten...

Comment: It's just as useful as opening a non-empty file with `std::ofstream`. Try `ostringstream oss{"1234567", std::ios_base::app};` . Or `std::ios_base::ate`

Comment: Well the point of stringstreams is that they are not files. No point in emulating file behavior in spite of usability. ::ate is the sensible default here.

Answer (score 3):

@IgorTandetnik gave your a solution - to add `std::ios_base::app` `std::ostringstream` constructor argument.

However, there is no benefit in passing the initial string (and only a string) into constructor. The argument still gets copied, similar to what `oss << "1234567";` does, but it requires providing an extra constructor argument which risks introducing a programming error (and it does in your code).

I suggest keeping it simple:

```
ostringstream oss;
oss << "1234567";
oss << "000";
// alternatively, just do oss << "1234567000";
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I wonder why ios_base::app is not the default mode, since the current one is not usable. The STL is still frustratingly unfriendly after so many updates to the standard...

Comment: @gatopeich IOStreams are often criticised for it poor design. Rightly, IMO.

Comment: Indeed, @Maxim. It looks like the main design goal of IOStreams was "to look very different to any other language specially C". The rest is details 