# std::ostringstream not initialized with std::string

Tags: c++, ostringstream

I tried to initialize a `std::ostringstream` with a `const std::string` but the string returned by the `str()` method does not include the initial string. I compile with a company toolchain based on gcc-4.3.2 with C++11 enabled.

**Example**

```cpp
#include <sstream>

const std::string str = "foo";
const std::string longStr = "barbarbar";

int main() {
  std::ostringstream ss1(str);
  std::ostringstream ss2{str};
  std::ostringstream ss3;
  ss3 << str;

  ss1 << longStr;
  ss2 << longStr;
  ss3 << longStr;

  std::cout << ss1.str() << std::endl;
  std::cout << ss2.str() << std::endl;
  std::cout << ss3.str() << std::endl;
}
```

**Result**

```
barbarbar
barbarbar
foobarbarbar
```

I expected all three lines to be equal, but only the `ss3` solution provided the right result. I tried this code on *code.sh* and it did what was expected: concatenating `str` and `longStr`.

I found a similar situation here without much explanations on why it behaves that way: [std::ostringstream overwriting initializing string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238203/stdostringstream-overwriting-initializing-string)

Why are the two first initializations not providing the expected result in my case?
What can make `std::ostringstream` behave differently in different compilation contexts?

Comment: The question in the dupe is not great, but the answer addresses your question.

Comment: Since the dupe doesn't provide a solution. You can redefine the `openstate` by adding it to the `ostringstream` constructor argument list `std::stringstream ss1(str, std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);` this will allow you to append strings afterwards. also works with initializer list `{}`.

Comment: Then why does it works without specifying these options in the constructor call?